# Loop error on <fieldset> tags - inserting closing tag before it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-apps-script

As part of a web app I'm building in Google Apps Script, I'm trying to create a checkbox field that shows one checkbox for each learner/student, arranged in rows of 3.  The learner data is being taken from a spreadsheet (this bit is working fine).

I want the checkboxes to look like this:

image of 6 checkboxes, in 2 rows of 3

[image: 1]

The problem I am having is that my code is inserting the closing fieldset tag in the wrong place (too early) and so the checkboxes don't look right (I'm using the jquery mobile 1.4.5 framework).

I've been staring at the code and tinkering with it for hours, I'm hoping it's something simple I just can't see and hoping someone can help me fix it.

The code I am using is basically a nested loop - the outer loop should create the fieldset tags for each row, and the inner loop should create each checkbox.  My code is as follows:

1. First the container div

```html
<div id="learners">Loading...</div>
```

2. The javascript to grab the data and replace the container div above with it...

```js
// The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showLearners)
        .getLearnerData();
  });

  function showLearners(learners) {
    var learnerCheckboxes = $('#learners');
    learnerCheckboxes.empty();
    var cols=['a','b','c'];

    for (var i = 0; i < learners.length; i++) {
      learnerCheckboxes.append("<fieldset class=\"ui-grid-b\">");

      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        learnerCheckboxes.append(
          "<div class=\"ui-block-" + cols[j] + "\">" +
            "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"learner\" id=\"learner" + i + "\" data-mini=\"true\">" +
            "<label for=\"learner" + i + "\">" + learners[i][0] + "</label>" +
          "</div>"
        );
        i++
      }

      learnerCheckboxes.append("</fieldset>");
    }
  }
```

The problem is, when the code runs, the closing `</fieldset>` is inserted too early... here's the output from this code:

```html
<div id="learners">
  <fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
  </fieldset><!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM - IT SHOULD BE AT THE BOTTOM OF THIS GROUP?-->
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="learner0" data-mini="true">
    <label for="learner0">David</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="learner1" data-mini="true">
    <label for="learner1">Dominic</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="learner2" data-mini="true">
    <label for="learner2">Eliza</label>
  </div>
  
  <fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
  </fieldset><!-- THIS SHOULD BE AT THE BOTTOM OF THIS GROUP-->
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="learner4" data-mini="true">
   <label for="learner4">Francois</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="learner5" data-mini="true">
    <label for="learner5">James</label></div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="learner6" data-mini="true">
    <label for="learner6">Louise</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where `empty()` and `append()` come from but shouldn't the checkboxes be appended to the `<fieldset>`.  Right now you are appending to `<div id="learners">Loading...</div>`.

Comment: empty() and append() are Jquery mobile functions - see for eg https://api.jquery.com/append/.

You are correct - the checkboxes should be appended to fieldset - but as I don't know how many fieldsets to create ahead of time (this is for a situation in which the number of users changes dynamically) I need to create these programmatically.  Which is why I'm using a nested loop with the fieldset open and close tags in the outer loop, and then inserting checkboxes between them in the inner loop... or that's why I'm trying to do (but failing at)

Comment: Just playing around with this some more and there is something going on, perhaps with jequery mobile, that I don't understand.  If I add a line to insert some text just before the closing `</fieldset>` tag... like this:
'learnerCheckboxes.append("**");\nlearnerCheckboxes.append("</fieldset>");`
`

Comment: Just playing around with this some more and there is something going on, perhaps with jequery mobile, that I don't understand.  If I add a line to insert some text just before the closing `</fieldset>`...  
  
    learnerCheckboxes.append("**");
    learnerCheckboxes.append("</fieldset>");
  
The output still inserts the closing `</fieldset>` tag before the checkboxes and before the two **'s - these are inserted as expected them to be after the checkboxes.
  
I don't understand why other than to guess that jquerymobile or google apps script is forcing the `<fieldset>` to be closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [TheWizEd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656739/thewized) for the idea to dynamically name the fieldset tags - this is what lead to the solution.  By dynamically creating the fieldset ID, I can use the inner loop to append the checkboxes BETWEEN the fieldset tags.  Here's the code:

```js
function showLearners(learners) {
  var learnerCheckboxes = $('#learners');
  learnerCheckboxes.empty();
  var cols=['a','b','c'];
  var rowCount = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < learners.length; i++) {
    //in this next line, use rowCount to create a unique fieldset id
    learnerCheckboxes.append("<fieldset class=\"ui-grid-b\" id=\"checkRow" + rowCount + "\"></fieldset>");
    //then grab it
    var checkRow = $("#checkRow" + rowCount)
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      //and append the checkboxes to the newly created fieldset
      checkRow.append(
        "<div class=\"ui-block-" + cols[j] + "\">" +
          "<div class=\"ui-checkbox ui-mini\">" +
            "<label for=\"learner" + i + "\" class=\"ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off\">" + 
              learners[i][0] + "</label>" +
            "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"learner\" id=\"learner" + i + "\" data-mini=\"true\">" +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>"
      );
      i++;//we're in the inner loop, so have to manually increment i
    }
    rowCount++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of trial and error because I don't use jquery.  I do it the old fashion way.  But I finally got it to work.  You can play with the CSS to get it to look like you want.

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="learners">Loading...</div>
    <script>
      (function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showLearners).getLearnerData();
      })();

      function showLearners(learners) {
        var learnerCheckboxes = $('#learners');
        learnerCheckboxes.empty();
        var cols=['a','b','c'];
        let i = 0;
        while( i < learners.length ) {
          let id = "fieldset"+i;
          let fieldset = $('<fieldset class="ui-grid-b" id="'+id+'"></fieldset>')
          learnerCheckboxes.append(fieldset);

          for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            let div = $('<div class="ui-block-' + cols[j] + '"></div>')
            fieldset.append(div);
            id = "learner"+i;
            let input = $('<input type="checkbox" name="learner" id="' + id + '" data-mini="true">');
            let label = $('<label for="' + id + '">' + learners[i][0] + '</label>' );
            div.append(input);
            div.append(label);
            i++;
            if( i === learners.length ) break;
          }

        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function getLearnerData() {
  try {
    Logger.log("In getLearnerData");
    return [["Dave"],["Tom"],["Larry"],["Mary"],["Joe"],["Sam"],["John"]];
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in getLearnerData: "+err);
  }
}
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: That's not quite the UI design I was looking for, however your idea of dynamically creating a unique ID for the fieldset was the inspiration I needed.  I can then use that unique ID to use the append function within the inner loop that lays out the checkboxes.